# diagram for wiring switch

Tags: electrical

old configuration had a switch at the end (two wire) wired to a light which had 12-3 (multiple lights).  I removed the light and want to wire the switch back in.  need configuration for connecting the 12-2 switch to 12-3 source.

Comment: What is this switch switching now? Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: That’s like saying I need the firing order for a 6 cylinder motor. We really need more information or photos . Is there a switched receptacle?